# Function returns zero, but why does it not fail when method spelled wrong?

Tags: javascript, function

In the for loop: counter < (x.lenght) is spelled wrong, but the function returns zero. When corrected to x.length the function returns the correct number of Bs, 3. 1) Why is zero being returned?  2) Why does javascript not catch this error?  3) For the future, anything I can do to make sure these types of errors are caught?

```
function countBs(x){
  var lCounter = 0;
  for (var counter = 0; counter < (x.lenght); counter++){
    if((x.charAt(counter)) == "B"){
        lCounter++;
       } 
  }  
  return lCounter;   
}
console.log(countBs("BCBDB"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing `x.lenght` is returning `undefined` causing the `for` loop to terminate immediately. Therefore the initial value of `lCounter` is returned.

You can check for the existence of a property in an object by using the `in` keyword like so:

```
if ( 'lenght' in x ) {
  ...
```

Comment: In addition to this please see some explanation about undefined properties and error catching for this error. Please see https://dmitripavlutin.com/7-tips-to-handle-undefined-in-javascript/

Comment: Is there a way to make javascript automatically catch a name error besides using in?

Comment: `x` is obviously a string, so `in` won't work on it.

Comment: I would suggest adding condition typeof if that helps. Please see some explanation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 3):

`x.lenght` is returning `undefined`. Comparison operators perform automatic type juggling, so `undefined` is converted to a number to perform the comparison, and it converts to `NaN`. Any comparison with `NaN` returns `false`, so the loop ends.

Javascript doesn't catch this error because it uses loose typing, automatically converting types as needed in most cases.

There's no easy way to ensure that typos like this are caught. A good IDE might be able to detect it if you provide good type comments.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does all kind of crazy coversions, instead of throwing an error: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp
'undefined' in particular becomes NaN when necessary (very last line of the very last table), which results in 'false' when compared to a number (regardless of <, >, <=, >=, == or !=, they all fail, NaN does not even equal to itself).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch or log an error to make sure your variable property is defined. Please see code below:

```
function countBs(x){
var lCounter = 0;
if(typeof x.lenght == 'undefined')
{
  console.log('Undefined poperty lenght on variable x');
  return 'Error catch';
}

  for (var counter = 0; counter < (x.lenght); counter++){
    if((x.charAt(counter)) == "B"){
        lCounter++;
       } 
  }  
  return lCounter;   
}
console.log(countBs("BCBDB"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To catch this *particular* error, set `lCounter` to -1 instead of 0.

That will ensure that the loop will run at least once *if* the `for` condition is correct.

You can return (or throw) an error if the loop isn't entered.

Otherwise, return `lCounter + 1` to account for the initialization of -1.

```
function countBs(x) {
  var lCounter = -1;

  for (var counter = 0; counter < (x.lenght); counter++) {
    if((x.charAt(counter)) == "B") {
      lCounter++;
    } 
  }

  if(lCounter == -1) {
    return 'Error';
  } else {
    return lCounter + 1;
  }
}
```